# How to understand this phpStan error (has parameter $astTreeData with no value type specified in iterable type array.)

Tags: php, phpdoc, phpstan

Say I have a formatter function like this:

```
function prepareValue(mixed $value): string
{
    ...
    return "{$value}";
}

/**
 * @param array<int, array> $astTreeData
 * @return string
 */
function makeFormattedDiff(array $astTreeData): string
{
    $statusTree = [
        'added' => function (string $path, array $node) {
            {some code...}
            return "Property '{$path}' was added with value: {$value}";
        },
        'deleted' => fn($path) => "Property '{$path}' was removed",
        'nested' => function (string $path, array $node, callable $iterRender) {
            {some code...}
            return $iterRender($children, $path);
        },
        'changed' => function (string $path, array $node) {
            {some code...}
            return "Property '{$path}' was updated. From {$valueBefore} to {$valueAfter}";
        },
        'unchanged' => fn() => [],
    ];

    /**
     * @param array<int, array> $diff
     * @return string
     */
    $renderPlainDiff = function (array $diff, string|bool $pathComposition) use (&$renderPlainDiff, $statusTree) {
        $diffCopy = $diff;
        $lines = array_reduce(
            $diffCopy,
            /**
             * @param array<int, string> $acc
             * @param array<string, array> $node
             * @param array|null $initial
             * @return array
             */
            function (array $acc, array $node, array|null $initial = []) use (
                $renderPlainDiff,
                $pathComposition,
                $statusTree
            ) {
                {some code...}
                $diffTypeHandler = $statusTree[$status];
                return flatten([$acc, $diffTypeHandler($newPath, $node, $renderPlainDiff)]);
            },
            []
        );

        return implode("\n", $lines);
    };

    return $renderPlainDiff($astTreeData, false);
}
```

All parameters and return values are specified in detail with phpdoc and type hinting syntax but phpStan gives an error message phpstan: `Function Differ\Formatters\plainFormatter\makeFormattedDiff() has parameter $astTreeData with no value type specified in iterable type array`

What iterable type array values need to be described?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1HCZ2.png)

Comment: The $astTreeData parameter is an array, but you're not saying an array of what. I'd say it's that, but I can't reproduce it on my end

Comment: OK. Maybe you mean something like 
`/**
 * @param array<int, array<int, array>> $astTreeData
 */

Comment: Yeah or array<mixed> or something, I don't know what's in there